# Getting content to clear a responsive image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive image outside of the body with the as in the code below. It fills the top half of the screen and is responsive, which is great, but I want all of the content underneath to stay underneath the image as it resizes but nothing is working - rather than clear the image it just sits over the top of it. Any ideas or alternative methods I could try?

The HTML:

```
</head>
<img src="/portfolio/images/me.jpg" class="ri">
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="contain">
            <a href="/"><img src="/portfolio/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="200" height="200"></a>
        </div>
    </header>
        <div class="contain">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/work">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/details">Details</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

The CSS:

```
    .contain {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img.ri {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 980px;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    z-index: -200;

}

        body {

    .lift {
    height: 80px;
    }

    header {
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you wanted if you used floats rather than position absolute; Also you image should not be outside off the body really.

See http://jsfiddle.net/BnCQp/ for an example

Code is like this

```
.contain {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float:left;
}

img.ri {
    float:left;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 980px;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    z-index: -200;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;}
.clearfix {
display: inline-block;}
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
```

Just add clearfix in your img tag as class="clearfix"